# How do I assign string to vertex in for loop?

Tags: java, dijkstra, vertex

I'm trying to impelement dijkstra algorithm in java. I try to get node names in a text file. I assigned node names in an array called []nodes

I add vertex in my project manually with this code:

```
Vertex a = new Vertex("a");
```

I want to assing vertex names from text file with a for loop with this code

```
for(int i=0; i< numOfNodes; i++){

        Vertex nodes[i] = new Vertex(nodes[i]);

    }
```

but it gives me this error

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The constructor Vertex(Vertex) is undefined
- Type mismatch: cannot convert from Vertex to 
 Vertex[]
- Syntax error on token "i", delete this token
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Highly suggest you post more of your code. It isnt clear what the posted code is trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't valid syntax; you need to define your `Vertex` array outside your for loop, and have the contents of the file stored somewhere else, i.e.

```
String text_input[] = new String[num_lines_in_file];
// Read the text file and store inputs in above array...
// ...

Vertex nodes[] = new Vertex[text_input.length];
for(int i=0; i< nodes.length; i++){
    nodes[i] = new Vertex(text_input[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently trying to create a `Vertex` with what I assume is a `String` (`nodes[i]`)

```
Vertex nodes[i] = new Vertex(nodes[i]);
```

But there in lies your problem. You're trying to insert a `Vertex` object back into the `String` array. You need an alternative array for `Vertex` objects.